# Collect inputs from two separate SharePoint lists and save results in a third list

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm building an app that has two screens, and these two screens are connected to two separate SharePoint lists.

Screen 1 is connected to the list 'Employees'. In this screen, I have an edit form with various fields related to individual employees, some are text freeform like Name and some are combo boxes (determined by the Sharepoint column's choices). When a user saves the form, it creates a new item in that list. [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JsQk.png).

In Screen 2, I have a Container that is connected to the list 'Checklist'. This list is different because it's already filled - each item is a question and these questions have corresponding columns that give more detail about the question. For each question there is also a Yes/No choice column.

The Container is split into a Gallery on the left, and a view form and edit form on the right (so that the Yes/No choice can be selected). It also has a dropdown list that selects the Names from my first Employees list. After a user completes the checklist and answers Yes or No next to each question, they then click Save. [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwo2A.png).

What I want to achieve is: the Save button taking everything from Screen 2 and saving it in a third SharePoint list called 'EmployeeChecklistScores'. I want it to take the employee name selected in the dropdown in Screen 2, but then calculate the Yes/No answers. If Yes then 1, if No then 0.

If the user answered 10 questions with Yes, then after clicking Save I want to have the EmployeeChecklistScores list showing two columns: Name (John Smith in this case) and Total score (10 in this case).

Basically, the purpose of this is to have is a checklist that can be filled out for each employee and then a total score calculated based on that.

Appreciate any advice here.

Edit (re comment below): [New save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOt5c.png).

Answer (score 0):

After the users submit their data on Screen1, you can refer to the data with `Form1.LastSubmit`.

PowerApps supports some data type coercing, so you can actually add up booleans:

```
true + true + false = 2
```

In your case, I believe Yes/No radio buttons would be better in Screen2 instead of the dropdown. This way, the user has to click anyway. In the OnChange of the radio element you can track their choices as booleans in a collection. You can then use a formula like `Sum(MyCollection.BooleanColumn)` to calculate the final score.

Also, if you are not planning on storing multiple results per employee, you could consider storing results simply in the first SharePoint list. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion. I've simplified things and used a gallery for the questions and a radio button for the answers. Here is what I've used for the save button - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOt5c.png - however it doesn't calculate the responses separately. If you pick yes in one and yes in the other it will still show 1 in total, whereas I want it to add up the responses (if two yes answers then a total of 2, if one yes and one no then a total of 1).

Comment: I checked your picture, and I don't think your formula is correct. You are using Sum() to evaluate Gallery.AllItems but you're not referencing any of its fields. Also, albeit not highlighted as an error, I guess referencing a control in the context of Gallery.AllItems would also not work. I still suggest you take the above recommended approach to ensure the calculation is dynamic.